# Inject list of initialized beans

Tags: java, spring

I need to inject list of already initialized beans into some another one.

I have class with definitions of some lazy beans which are used depending on environment - like on server 1 only `impl1` and `impl2` will be used and on server 2 `impl3` and `impl1`

```
@Component
class Definitions {
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public A impl1() { /* ... */ }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public A impl2() { /* ... */ }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public A impl3() { /* ... */ }
}
```

And I have some monitoring bean which don't know anything about environment and just collects all those `A` beans exposing some health information for actuator:

```
@Component
class Monitoring implements HealthIndicator {
    @Autowired
    private List<A> monitored;
}
```

Problem is that spring wires all beans into `monitored` even if they were not initialized before (which crashes the whole thing, cause there is no suitable environment). And I need to somehow explain to spring that I only need already initialized beans - something like `@AutowireOnlyThoseLazyBeansWhichAlreadyBeenUsedSomewhereElse`

P.S. I know that I can use dirty hack and declare a list property inside `Definitions`, fill it in bean factory methods and register another one bean with reference to that list but it is too dirty.

Comment: Maybe you could just use `@Autowired(required=false)`?

Comment: @RandallFlagg, it forces eager instantiation of beans so the whole app crashes on missing environment. So it either not working as expected or I need something that won't force my beans to instantiate immediately.

Comment: Use profiles and on different servers specify the profiles to apply.

Comment: @M.Deinum, It won't solve the problem.

Comment: Trust me it will as only those beans that match the profile will be loaded and present in the application context.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I meant that this is not the solution I'm looking for, at least because it is also hack (profiles as I understand them are not suitable for that kind of tasks). Also I don't want users of that class to think about what profile and how they should use to make that work properly. 

Currently there are definitions of some connections present in the above style and all I (or other team member) need to do to add new connection is to place new definition and I don't need to care if it is used anywhere or not.

Comment: I would argue that the way you are using `@Lazy` now is the actual hack. Instead you should implement your `@Conditional` which makes beans conditional under certain rules (profile is a sample of that). So I suggest to implement those rules instead of hacking with `@Lazy`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't think so (how else could lazy be used? :) ). Anyway, I asked about "how to inject already instantiated beans" and not "how to change some agreements in my code and rewrite some core classes of my app" for latter I would better ask on CodeReview.SE not at SO.

Comment: The solution is to not use `@Autowired` as that will eagerly instantiate those beans (I suggest a read on what `@Lazy` actually is and that is exactly why it is a hack imho). `@Autowired` will look for all beans of a certain type and create them if necessary. If that isn't what you want inject the `ApplicationContext` and use the appropriate `getBean` method. But as mentioned imho you are using `@Lazy` wrong (or at least your understanding is wrong/off especially in combination with injection bean collections).

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to just write custom OSGi-like "ServiceTracker" through monitoring beans of some specific type via BeanPostProcessor and registering dynamic bean with all tracked beans in concurrent map into context.